# Compiling Asterisk on Windows

Tags: windows, cygwin, asterisk

I was trying to compile Asterisk 1.6 on Windows using Cygwin

1- I have installed Cygwin and included (Debug, Devel and Libs )while installing Cygwin.

2- ./Configure passed successfully

3- while running make command I got this

```
 In file included from /home/Administrator/asterisk-1.6.2.24/include/asterisk.h:27:0,
                     from smsq.c:20:
    /home/Administrator/asterisk-1.6.2.24/include/asterisk/compat.h:205:28: error: conflicting types for ‘uint64_t’
     typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
                                ^
    In file included from /usr/include/stdint.h:14:0,
                     from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/stdint.h:9,
                     from /usr/include/inttypes.h:19,
                     from /home/Administrator/asterisk-1.6.2.24/include/asterisk/compat.h:29,
                     from /home/Administrator/asterisk-1.6.2.24/include/asterisk.h:27,
                     from smsq.c:20:
    /usr/include/sys/_stdint.h:60:20: note: previous declaration of ‘uint64_t’ was here
     typedef __uint64_t uint64_t ;
                        ^
    make[1]: *** [/home/Administrator/asterisk-1.6.2.24/Makefile.rules:91: smsq.o] Error 1
    make: *** [Makefile:422: utils] Error 2
```

I need to know what is the cause and how can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to compile a version of Asterisk that's 8 years old? That's bound to end up poorly.

Comment: because I have a Dialogic Analog  card which is compatible with Asterisk 1.6

Answer (score 0):

The type named `uint64_t` is defined in `<stdint.h>` where it should be, but asterisk is (wrongly, all identifiers ending in `_t` are reserved names) trying to provide its own definition.

Remove the improper definition in `"compat.h"`.

Comment: do you mean remove every definition ends with _t ?